# Как реализовать такую сетку?

Tags: jquery, css3, html5, javascript

Есть ли уже готовые плагины для того чтобы реализовать сетку новостей как на [имхонете](http://imhonet.ru/)?

(и да я знаю что реализованно с помощью position absolute и можно еще и с transform, но нужен именно плагин)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Плагин [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html). Элементы можно выстраивать как вам угодно.

Ну, и как его следствие, плагин [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

Будет как в пинтересте и имхонете.

Answer (score 2):

Там же просто 4 или 5 колонок, господин [@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis) предлагает такое решения вопроса с колонками: http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/2E4dH/

Comment: Решение господина @Deonis не совсем кроссбраузерно, н-р, в IE7 колонки располагаются друг под другом.

Это: 

    div > div {
      display: inline-block;
      background: #dcdcdc;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 5px;
    }

можно было доработать так:

    div > div {
      background: #dcdcdc;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 5px;
      display:-moz-inline-stack;
      display:inline-block;
      _overflow:hidden;/*IE6, IE7*/
      *zoom:1;/*включаем hasLayout для IE6, IE7*/
      *display:inline;/*при hasLayout true display:inline в IE6, IE7 ведёт себя как display:inline-block*/
    }

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте плагин "masonry"